# Where can a startup seek funding from block.one for building out EOS applications?

Tags: dapp, block.one, funding

Is there a place where one can goto for funding from block.one for building out EOS apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Block.one has a venture capital arm named [EOS VC](https://vc.eos.io/) where they fund new projects that build on the EOSIO protocol:

> EOS VC invests across sectors, and focuses on projects that have the highest likelihood of delivering value through the application of blockchain technology. This includes: social media, gaming, entertainment, fintech, healthcare, supply chain and logistics.

To apply, you can use [the form on the website](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSemBIYCtBlMttHj5wxVECmcj5k-JdutLr4Jtj0BrfFWZlI_5g/viewform), or you can contact them using the [contact page](https://vc.eos.io/contact/).